# kivy buildozer permission denied

Tags: python, kivy

I tried to compile my app with buildozer, but I got this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'/home/gilgamesch/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/enemyd.png'
```

Why is the permission denied?

Comment: Can you please post your code or a minimally complete example?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why the permission is denied, but I had the same issue. A workaround is to run the build command as sudo. You'll get a warning telling you not do so, but I never had any troubles afterwards. So you would type something like:
sudo buildozer android debug

Comment: did you try to chown that files first, and actually check permissions on them?